# How would I need to variablize sql insert into, generic values, which columns and values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, xlrd

The issue I am having is: Columns in the Excel change daily. If I add a column's name in the insert into section, %s section, for loop section, and the values in the for loop and the column is not in the Excel, the script throws an error stating: "first_column_name_db" assigned before it is used

If it is possible, How would I variableize the insert into section, the %s section, which columns are found in the Excel, and the values inserted into the DB table?

Lines are only added in the INSERT INTO section, %s section, Excel For Loop, and values section when a column is found/located inside the Excel.

Or is there a better way of stepping over the lines within each section if the column is not found/located in the Excel and what is found still inserts into the db table?

(**I also added comments within the code above INSERT INTO and %s VALUES, For loop for the Excel, and the values inside the for loop** The first 2 For loop's are only there for searching column indexes by name)

The variables for the insert into, %s, excel columns, and values are called based on which columns are found in the Excel.
I am unsure if a list would work or not.
I am stuck on how I should start/proceed with accomplishing this task.

```
        import psycopg2
        import xlrd

        try:
            conn = psycopg2.connect(user = 'Username', password = 'Password', host = 'Host_name', database = 'DB_name', port = Port_number)
            mycursor = conn.cursor()

            print('DB connection open')
            print('XLRD Data inserting into DB Table')

            #Open the excel
            book = xlrd.open_workbook('excel_name.xlsx')
            #Use Index # for Which worksheet or use by_sheet_name......
            sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)

            #Loop row index's
            for rowidx in range(sheet.nrows):
                row = sheet.row(rowidx)
                #Loop Column index's
                for colidx, cell in enumerate(row):
                    #Cell value Text for Header name
                    if cell.value == "Header_Name_Column_A":
                        #Varablize header index #
                        header_name_a_index = colidx

                    if cell.value == "Header_Name_Column_B":
                        #Varablize header index #
                        header_name_b_index = colidx

                    if cell.value == "Header_Name_Column_C":
                        #Varablize header index #
                        header_name_c_index = colidx

                    if cell.value == "Header_Name_Column_D":
                        #Varablize header index #
                        header_name_d_index = colidx

                    #INSERT INTO lines are only added if columns are found or located in the Excel
                    #VALUES of %s are updated based on locating/finding columns in the Excel
                    sql = """INSERT INTO db_table_name(
                    first_column_name_db,
                    second_column_name_db,
                    third_column_name_db,
                    fourth_column_name_db
                    )

                    VALUES(
                    %s,
                    %s,
                    %s,
                    %s)"""

                    #loop through all rows and cells
                    for r in range(1, sheet.nrows):
                        #The columns are added as they are located/found in the Excel
                        first_column_name_db = sheet.cell(r, header_name_a_index).value
                        second_column_name_db = sheet.cell(r, header_name_b_index).value
                        third_column_name_db = sheet.cell(r, header_name_c_index).value
                        fourth_column_name_db = sheet.cell(r, header_name_d_index).value

                        #The values are updated based on the columns located/found in the Excel
                        values = (
                        first_column_name_db,
                        second_column_name_db,
                        third_column_name_db,
                        fourth_column_name_db
                        )

                        mycursor.execute(sql, values)

                    #Commit to the DB. Close the mycursor and conn.
                    mycursor.close()
                    conn.commit()
                    conn.close()

        except Exception as e:
            #Close cursor and connection if error
            mycursor.close()
            conn.close()
            print('Error')
            print(e)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create the `sql` and `values` dynamically by determining - in your first `for` loop - which values exists, then keep a list of tuples of the values and indexes that need to be input to the database.

For examples, you might initialize a new list each outer `for` iteration:

```
sqlCols = []
```

then add the last lines to each conditional in the `colidx, cell in enumerate(row):` loop:

```
if cell.value == "Header_Name_Column_A":
    #Varablize header index #

    sqlCols.append(('first_column_name_db',colidx))
```

Then when you get to your `INSERT` command, you can define your sql string and sql values only if that column exists:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO db_table_name("+','.join([x[0] for x in sqlCols])+") VALUES("+','.join(['%s' for _ in range(len(sqlCols))])+")"
```

And because the tuple (column_name,column_index) in each element of sqlCols always matches name to index, it doesn't matter in what order you write your values, so that can be reduced to

```
for r in range(1, sheet.nrows):
    #The columns are added as they are located/found in the Excel
    #The values are updated based on the columns located/found in the Excel

    values = [sheet.cell(r,x[1]).value for x in sqlCols]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @jshrimp29 I will try this when I get home and reply to let you know what happens.

Comment: Reply to @jshrimp29 The code updates you helped me with are sweet. I am new to coding and I have a lot to learn still. I learn as I go and I never went school for development.
I made the updates to each section of my code as you explained in your response. I did not run an insert yet, that is next. 
One adjustment I had to make was lining the sql line, the for loop for the excel with the rowidx for loop or it would keep looping.

Comment: Reply to @jshrimp29 Not enough characters to add the coding updates.
I printed out each section of the code updates:
>>> 
DB connection open
XLRD Data inserting into DB Table
[('first_column_name_db', 0), ('second_column_name_db', 1), ('third_column_name_db', 2), ('fourth_column_name_db', 3)]
[1.0, 'yes1', 'now1', 'blah1']
[2.0, 'yes2', 'now2', 'blah2']
[3.0, 'yes3', 'now3', 'blah3']
[4.0, 'yes4', 'now4', 'blah4']
[5.0, 'yes5', 'now5', 'blah5']
[6.0, 'yes6', 'now6', 'blah6']
>>>

Comment: Replying to @jshrimp29 thank you for your help. Sorry for the delay. Inserts into the DB table. Only issue I am seeing, is 1 column duplicates in the SQL line. I&#39;m working on finding a resolution on my own. To see if I can figure this out and why. Thank you again for your help. Very much appreciated.